# How to make activeX dll in Delphi XE and add it to Excel VBA project like a reference

Tags: delphi, excel, activex, vba

I have a question. How to make activeX dll in Delphi XE and add it to Excel VBA project like a reference.

I made the usual activeX library (file -> new -> other -> activeX -> activeX Library). Wrote several functions and procedures inside it. And build. So I have "SomeActiveXLibrary.dll"

Now I'd like to use my dll in vba project in excel. In vba IDE I push tools->references->browse->"SomeActiveXLibrary.dll" and see "can't add a reference to the specified file".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have never worked with Delphi but see if this link helps? http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?532719-RESOLVED-Can-t-add-a-reference-to-the-specified-file

Comment: That's not an ActiveX library. An ActiveX library needs a COM or Automation object, a type library, and needs to be registered with Windows via `RegSvr32` or Delphi's `TRegSvr`. You have a DLL, which needs to have individual functions registered as externals in your VBA code.

Answer (score 2):

Like Ken White said, you have only done half of what is needed to make a viable ActiveX DLL.  You created the DLL itself, but did not put an ActiveX object inside of it.  After using "File > New > Other > ActiveX > ActiveX Library", you need to then use "File > New > Other > ActiveX > COM Object" to add an ActiveX/COM object to the library.  Then you can flesh out the generated TypeLibrary and implementation class with your custom functions as needed, compile the DLL, and register it.  Then VB/VBA should be able to use it.